Radon-Nikodym derivatives with restricted support
Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ and $g$ be two PDFs of two random variables. Then we can write:
$$f(x) = \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}(x) \qquad g(x) = \frac{d \nu}{d \lambda}(x)$$
where $\nu$ and $\mu$ are the probability measures corresponding to the two random variables. By chain-rule, we get:
$$\frac{f}{g} = \frac{\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}}{\frac{d \nu}{d \lambda}} = \frac{d \mu}{d \nu}$$
Question:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are both log-normal (say with different means for argument's sake): then quite clearly, we must assume that the above formulas are only valid for $x>0$, correct? Log-normal random variables only have non-zero densities for $x>0$, so clearly we cannot carry out a division by zero for $g(x): x<0$ ?? Is this notion formalized in the Radon-Nikodym theorem? To my knowledge, the theorem only states that the measures need to be absolutely continuous with respect to one another.

Suppose $f$ is Normal and $g$ is log-normal: then am I right to assume that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is undefined? (well, since the corresponding measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ would not be absolutely continuous in this case (they disagree on zero-measure sets), then the Radon-Nikodym theorem cannot be applied: so indeed, I would expect the Radon-Nikodym derivative to be undefined. What is confusing is that the chain-rule formula above is often used without an explicit reference to the Radon-Nikodym theorem, and then it makes it look as if it can be used universaly).



The chain rule is valid if in addition it is known that $mu\ell \nu$. For example, uniform distributions $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ supported on $[-1,0]$ and $[1,0]$ are of course absolutely continuous with resect to Lebesgue measure: $f_1=\frac{d\mu_1}{d\lambda}=\mathbb{1}{[-1,0]}$ and $f_2=\frac{d\mu_2}{d\lambda}=\mathbb{1}{[0,1]}$. The measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are mutually singular however;thus the absolutely continuous part of $\mu_1$ w.r.t. $\mu_2$ is $0$. Of course $f_1/f_2=0$ $\mu_2$-a.s. and $f_1/f_2=\infty$ $\mu_1$-a.s.

@Mittens: Thank you so much for this answer, it clarifies it a lot. Apologies for my ignorance, because sadly, I never got to study the subject rigorously whilst at university: am I right to assume that $\ell$ means "mutually absolutely continuous" ?

Sorry I mean to write $\mu\ll \nu$. The means that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$, that is $\mu(A)=0$ whenever $\nu(A)=0$. Under this circumstances, the Radon Nykodym theorem implies the existence of a function (measurable) $f$ such that $\mu(B)=\int_B fd\nu$ for all measurable sets $B$, $f$ is denoted as $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$. (this is ok since in your case $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures ($\sigma$-finite will be all right too.))

On the opposite extremum, two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are mutually singular if there is a measurable set $B$ such that $\mu_1(B)=0=\mu_2(\Omega\setminus B)$.
